# Figuring out which AngularJS functions are called

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Suppose we have the following code from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_application.asp):

```
<script>
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
});
</script>

<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in products">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want to know exactly which functions (from angular.js code) are being called from the very beginning. Is there a way to do that? In other words, if I do not have an HTML file, can I reproduce the effects of angular.js?

I have already used Chrome dev tools, and it did not answer my problem.

Comment: "I have already used Chrome dev tools, and it did not answer my problem." Have you tried putting a breakpoint at the very first line of the `<script>` element and walking through with the debugger?  That would give you a full tour of what is happening, although it would probably be time-consuming-- the guts of big libraries like that tend to pass through several layers of abstraction when executing.    What is it you are trying to accomplish and why?  That context may help the community provide you with an answer more tailored to your use case.

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Bootstrap - Automatic Initilization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#automatic-initialization).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Docs:

> ## Automatic Initialization
>
> AngularJS initializes automatically upon `DOMContentLoaded` event or when the `angular.js` script is evaluated if at that time `document.readyState` is set to 'complete'. At this point AngularJS looks for the `ngApp` directive which designates your application root. If the `ngApp` directive is found then AngularJS will:
>
> - load the module associated with the directive.
> - create the application injector
> - compile the DOM treating the ngApp directive as the root of the compilation. This allows you to tell it to treat only a portion of the DOM as an AngularJS application.
>
> [image]

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Bootstrap - Automatic Initilization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#automatic-initialization).